# More than one field has the JSON key for name "quantity"

Tags: json, flutter, dart, model

Flutter json_serializable i want to use same key with two different Variables Here is my Code how do i make that below example is i want to get quantity key and use it with two different  variables? thanks

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'food_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true,)
class FoodModel {
  String? id;
  String? name;

  String? status;
  String? description;
  double? price;
  @JsonKey(name: "quantity")
  int quantity = 1;
  String? category;
  @JsonKey(name: "quantity")
  int? availableQuantity;
  double? initialPrice;
  String? location;
  List<Images>? images;

  FoodModel(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.status,
      this.location,
      this.description,
      this.category,
      this.price,
      this.quantity = 1});

  factory FoodModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$FoodModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FoodModelToJson(this);

}
```

Comment: Won't work.  Proper JS objects cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by implementing custom read function:

```
part 'food_model.g.dart';

int? _readQuantity(Map map, String key) => int.tryParse(map['quantity']);

@JsonSerializable(
  explicitToJson: true,
)
class FoodModel {
  FoodModel({
    int quantity = 1,
    @JsonKey(readValue: (_readQuantity)) int? availableQuantity,
  });

  factory FoodModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FoodModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FoodModelToJson(this);
}
```